# Unable to change height of input:type="submit" button

Tags: html, css, button, height

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Set Alarm Clock</title>
<style type="text/css">
#container {
width: 600px;
height: 300px;
border: 1px solid black;
}
#hours, #minutes, #seconds {
width: 120px;
height: 80px;
}
#button {
width: 120px;
height: 80px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<div id="container">
<h1>Set Alarm Clock</h1><br />
<label class="hours">
<input type="number" value="0" min="0" id="hours" />
</label>
<label class="minutes">
<input type="number" value="0" min="0" id="minutes" />
</label>
<label class="seconds">
<input type="number" value="0" min="0" id="seconds" />
</label>
<label>
<input type="submit" value="Set Alarm" id="button" />
</label>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to make the `input:type="submit"` button the same height as the labels for the hours, minutes and seconds boxes i have created. However i can only change the width of the button, not the height. How can i make the height the exact same as the labels? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Button includes the padding and the border attributes by default.
You can just add  `box-sizing: content-box;` to the button.

```
#button {
width: 120px;
height: 80px;
box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z7Lkee07/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Button should be 86px height:

```
#button {
    width: 120px;
    height: 86px;
}
```

It is happening because the height of the button is including the paddings and the border. 86px is the whole height of the button.

Answer (score 0):

Please update the `#button` id with the `box-sizing` attribute. Please Click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fanafazil/yr2vm2eu/) to see resolved issue.

```
#button {
  width: 120px;
  height: 80px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```